# GemFire - Spring Boot Configuration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-gemfire

I am working on a project that has a requirement of Pivotal GemFire.
I am unable to find a proper tutorial about how to configure gemFire with Spring Boot.

I have created a partitioned Region and I want to configure Locators as well, but I need only server-side configuration as client is handled by someone else.

I am totally new to Pivotal GemFire and really confused.  I have tried creating a `cache.xml` but then somehow a `cache.out.xml` gets created and there are many issues.

Comment: Also i cant use gfsh commands, I need to have properties files or hard coded.

Answer (score 2):

@Priyanka-

Best place to start is with the Guides on spring.io.  Specifically, have a look at...

"[Accessing Data with GemFire](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-gemfire/)"

There is also...

"[Cache Data with GemFire](https://spring.io/guides/gs/caching-gemfire/)", and...

"[Accessing GemFire Data with REST](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-gemfire-data-rest/)"

However, these guides focus mostly on "client-side" application concerns, "data access" (over REST), "caching", etc.

Still, you can use *Spring Data GemFire* (in a *Spring Boot* application even) to configure a GemFire Server.  I have many examples of this.  One in particular...

"[Spring Boot GemFire Server Example](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-boot-gemfire-server-example)"

This example demonstrates how to bootstrap a *Spring Boot* application as a GemFire Server (technically, a peer node in the cluster).  Additionally, the GemFire properties are specified *Spring* config and can use *Spring's* normal conventions (property placeholders, SpEL expression) to configure these properties, like so...

https://github.com/jxblum/spring-boot-gemfire-server-example/blob/master/src/main/java/org/example/SpringBootGemFireServer.java#L59-L84

This particular configuration makes the GemFire Server a "GemFire Manager", possibly with an embedded "Locator" (indicated by the `start-locator` GemFie property, not to be confused with the "locators" GemFire property which allows our node to join and "existing" cluster) as well as a [GemFire CacheServer](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-boot-gemfire-server-example/blob/master/src/main/java/org/example/SpringBootGemFireServer.java#L96-L112) to serve GemFire cache clients (with a `ClientCache`).

This example creates a ["Factorials" Region](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-boot-gemfire-server-example/blob/master/src/main/java/org/example/SpringBootGemFireServer.java#L114-L127), with a [CacheLoader](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-boot-gemfire-server-example/blob/master/src/main/java/org/example/SpringBootGemFireServer.java#L122) (definition [here](https://github.com/jxblum/spring-boot-gemfire-server-example/blob/master/src/main/java/org/example/SpringBootGemFireServer.java#L140-L166)) to populate the "Factorials" Region on cache misses.

Since this example starts an embedded GemFire Manager in the *Spring Boot* GemFire Server application process, you can even connect to it using *Gfsh*, like so...

`gfsh> connect --jmx-manager=localhost[1099]`

Then you can run "gets" on the "Factorial" Region to see it compute factorials of the numeric keys you give it.

To see more advanced configuration, have a look at my other repos, in particular the *Contacts Application* RI ([here](https://github.com/jxblum/contacts-application)).

Hope this helps!

-John

Answer (score 1):

Well, I had the same problem, let me share with you what worked for me, in this case I'm using Spring Boot and Pivotal GemFire as cache client.

1. [Install](https://pivotal.io/pivotal-gemfire) and run GemFire
2. Read the [15 minutes quick start guide](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/gemfire/getting_started/15_minute_quickstart_gfsh.html)
3. Create a locator(let's call it `locator1`) and a server(`server1`) and a region(`region1`)
4. Go to the folder where you started the '*Gee Fish*'(`gfsh`) and then go to the locator's folder and open the log file, in that file you can get the *port* your locator is using.

Now let's see the Spring boot side:

1. In you Application with the `main` method add the `@EnablegemFireCaching` annotation
2. In the method(wherever it is) you want to cache, add the `@Cacheable("region1")` annotation.
3. Now let's create a *configuration file* for the caching:

   //this is my working class

   @Configuration
   public class CacheConfiguration {

   ```
   @Bean
   ClientCacheFactoryBean gemfireCacheClient() {
       return new ClientCacheFactoryBean();
   }

   @Bean(name = GemfireConstants.DEFAULT_GEMFIRE_POOL_NAME)
   PoolFactoryBean gemfirePool() {

       PoolFactoryBean gemfirePool = new PoolFactoryBean();

       gemfirePool.addLocators(Collections.singletonList(new ConnectionEndpoint("localhost", HERE_GOES_THE_PORT_NUMBER_FROM_STEP_4)));
       gemfirePool.setName(GemfireConstants.DEFAULT_GEMFIRE_POOL_NAME);
       gemfirePool.setKeepAlive(false);
       gemfirePool.setPingInterval(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(5));
       gemfirePool.setRetryAttempts(1);
       gemfirePool.setSubscriptionEnabled(true);
       gemfirePool.setThreadLocalConnections(false);

       return gemfirePool;
   }

   @Bean
   ClientRegionFactoryBean<Long, Long> getRegion(ClientCache gemfireCache, Pool gemfirePool) {
       ClientRegionFactoryBean<Long, Long> region = new ClientRegionFactoryBean<>();
       region.setName("region1");
       region.setLookupEnabled(true);
       region.setCache(gemfireCache);
       region.setPool(gemfirePool);
       region.setShortcut(ClientRegionShortcut.PROXY);

       return region;
   }
   ```

   That's all!, also do not forget to serialize(`implements Serializable`) the class is being cached(The class your cached method is returning)